# Why does one IDE not let me add parameters for JComboBox?

Tags: java, string, swing, parameters, jcombobox

I have two Java IDEs that I alternate between. jGRASP is for simpler tests and miscellaneous files, and Netbeans I use for more complex projects.

I'm currently using jGRASP and I'm trying to declare a `JComboBox<String>` object, but when I try to compile it, it gives me the message:

```
type javax.swing.JComboBox does not take parameters
```

But when I use `JComboBox` in Netbeans and set its parameter type to `String`, it doesn't give me that error. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for generics was only added to [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) in Java 1.7. Your `jGRASP` IDE is probably using an earlier version of Java

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages" in jGRASP to see which "javac" is being called during compilation. Look for the "actual command sent" line in the output.

On Windows, jGRASP will look for the newest version of Java when it starts and use that to run itself and run/compile your programs. If the Java part of the registry is futzed up, this may fail. You can use "Settings" > "jGRASP Startup Settings" to manually select a Java installation. If you do that, just remember to change it when you upgrade Java (probably just change it back to [default]).